# CSS solution - always scroll overflow doc to bottom

Tags: css

I have a div that has `overflow: scroll`, and I want it to always scroll to bottom along Y-axis no matter what content it has. (think about a chat thread, which always displays the latest message at the bottom.)

I saw there are some jQuery solutions that scrolls the div to its height when new messages get added, but I am wondering if there's any pure CSS solution to this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, not possible with pure CSS but you can use pure js to get the total scrollable height of element with `elem.scrollHeight` and scroll the element to that position with `elem.scrollTop`

[you can see in this example](https://jsfiddle.net/k1fnohLd/1/)

the js code is:

```
var elem = document.querySelector("theElementClass");
var elemHeight = elem.scrollHeight;
elem.scrollTop = elemHeight;
```

hope this helps. =D